# How to set fixed width and height to svg

Tags: css, svg

I want to have fixed dimensions for a marker icon `width: 24px` and `height: 34px`, but `width` and `height` don't work.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="background-size:24px 34px;" xml:space="preserve" width="24px" height="34px">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
        .st1{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#B71C1C;}
        .st2{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#FFFFFF;}
    </style>
    <g id="Group_1_" transform="translate(7.000004, 5.000002)">
        <path class="st0" d="M5,1.1c-2.9,0-5.2,2.3-5.2,5.2c0,2.3,1.3,3.9,2.4,5.2c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.8,1c0.6,0.8,0.8,1.5,0.9,1.9
        C4.1,15,4.3,15.6,5,15.6s0.9-0.6,1.1-1.1s0.4-1.1,0.9-1.9c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.8-1c1.1-1.3,2.4-2.9,2.4-5.2C10.2,3.4,7.9,1.1,5,1.1z" />
        <path class="st1" d="M5,1.6c-2.6,0-4.7,2.1-4.7,4.7c0,2.8,2,4.4,3.1,5.9C4.6,14,4.3,15,5,15s0.4-1.1,1.6-2.8
        C7.7,10.7,9.7,9,9.7,6.3C9.7,3.7,7.6,1.6,5,1.6" />
        <path class="st2" d="M5,4.5c1,0,1.8,0.8,1.8,1.8S6,8.1,5,8.1S3.2,7.3,3.2,6.3S4,4.5,5,4.5" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: it is working in the snippet

Comment: I think `width` and `height` attributes are meant to be unitless on `<svg>` elements, just like they are with `<img>` elements.

Comment: Marker in svg doesn't have dimensions width 24px and height 34px.

Comment: Are you saying you want the marker art itself to be 24px by 34px?

Comment: Add a border or a background to see the svg element.: it works. If you want to stretch the pin try adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg element.

Comment: @Sean yes, exactly.

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` didn't help.

Comment: @Matt You'll need to adjust the `viewBox` to crop the SVG tightly to the marker art: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaned up your SVG because you are stacking dimension settings on dimension settings

Up to you to play with `viewBox`, `translate` and `width`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 180" width="120">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
    <g transform="translate(9, 5)">
        <path fill="white"
            d="m50 11c-29 0-52 23-52 52c0 23 13 39 24 52c3 4 6 7 8 10c6 8 8 15 9 19c2 6 4 12 11 12s9-6 11-11s4-11 9-19c2-3 5-7 8-10c11-13 24-29 24-52c0-30-23-53-52-53z" />
        <path fill="#B71C1C"
            d="m50 16c-26 0-47 21-47 47c0 28 20 44 31 59c12 18 9 28 16 28s4-11 16-28c11-15 31-32 31-59c0-26-21-47-47-47" />
        <path fill="white" d="m50 45c10 0 18 8 18 18s-8 18-18 18s-18-8-18-18s8-18 18-18" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

- `d=` paths were **multiplied by 10** in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor
- That **multiplied** the `viewBox` by 10 and got rid of all decimals
- Then I resized the `viewBox`
- Your original had a `translate(7,5)` but it needed an extra shift to-the-right to align in the green rectangle.

#### Simplified:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 180" width="120">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
    <path fill="#B71C1C" stroke="white" stroke-width="5"
        d="m60 16c-29 0-52 23-52 52c0 23 13 39 24 52c3 4 6 7 8 10c6 8 8 15 9 19c2 6 4 12 11 12s9-6 11-11s4-11 9-19c2-3 5-7 8-10c11-13 24-29 24-52c0-30-23-53-52-53z" />
    <circle cx="50%" cy="63" r="18" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you figure out to update `g` to `transform="translate(9, 5)"`?

Comment: d Paths where multiplied by 10 in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ That multiplied the viewBox by 10 and got rid of all decimals.. Then I resized the viewBox. Your original had ``translate(7,5)`` but it needed an extra shift to-the-right to align in the green rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very helpful